# How to use enums in basic script from an activex dll/tlb reference late bound

Tags: vba, dll, vbscript, reference, activex

TLDR:
**I am writing and testing a script from VBA but it is ultimately executed as a single `.bas` file from the main desktop application.**

**The DLL Reference is lost from VBA to the `bas` forcing me to define the application's members types as "object" instead of their native type in the `.bas` file.**

Can I avoid converting early-bound to late-bound code by defining a reference in the bas file?

---

More info:
I need to convert vba scripts to a basic script which the software can execute. Is there anyway within the basic script to reference the tlb file? I call the application using `set app = CreateObject("...")` The examples show everything typed as an "object" in their examples which gives no intellisense from VBA(of course)

Is it possible to reference the enums as their text value without converting them back to their integer value? Also, is there a way to properly type the application objects instead of using `object` in a basic script?

Comment: Enums aren't text values, they're `Long` integers with a name, and the name is an identifier, not a `String`. What are you trying to do? You're not getting intellisense because you're declaring `app As Object` which means all member calls get resolved at runtime (i.e. they're late-bound calls). If you're referencing the library then there's no need to write late-bound code. `Set app = New ThatLibrary.WhateverThatIs` and you'll get intellisense, assuming `Dim app As ThatLibrary.WhateverThatIs`.

Comment: Tools > References... > browse to the .tlb file, done.

Comment: @Mat'sMug I've clarified my question. I am writing from VBA with the refernce and getting intellisense, but need to move the VBA to BAS script and the VBA reference is gone.

Comment: @Mat'sMug converting early bound to late-bound would be nice, but I want to know if I can avoid the conversion all together. Can I just use early binding by defining some reference in the `bas` file? ..I'll update my question

Comment: A .bas file doens't have references, it's just a plain text file, with hardly any metadata. References belong to a `VBProject` object. There's no way you can avoid the conversion if you want that .bas file to be executable outside the VBE.

Comment: @Mat'sMug That answers part of my question. Then, how can I use an enum from a late-bound object?

Comment: You don't. You use its underlying integer value.

Comment: @Mat'sMug Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/161316/discussion-between-gismofx-and-mats-mug).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Can I avoid converting early-bound to late-bound code by defining a reference in the bas file?

No, you can't. A .bas file doesn't contain such metadata. In fact the only metadata it holds, is the name of the module, stored as a hidden `VB_Name` attribute that the VBE uses to populate the module's `Name` property.

References belong to a `VBProject` object; if you want a .bas file to stand on its own and be executable outside the VBE through VBScript runtime, then you **must** convert your early-bound code to late-bound.

This means you indeed lose intellisense, because all the types defined in that late-bound library must now be declared as `Object`, and enum values need to be converted to their underlying integer values.

Alternatively you can define same-name constants for these enums, and keep the names:

```
Private Const SomeEnumValue As Long = 42
```

Or, [re]define the enums yourself:

```
Private Enum SoneEnum
    SomeEnumValue = 42
    '...
End Enum
```